# Building multi-architecture docker images with Skaffold

Tags: docker, kubernetes, arm64, pi, skaffold

I've been able to get two awesome technologies to work independently.

- [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold)
- [BuildX](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/)

Unfortunatly I don't know how to use them both at the same time.

I'm currently building and testing on my laptop (amd), then deploying to a Raspberri Pi 4 (arm64) running Kubernetes.

To get this working I use something like:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --tag my-registry/my-image:latest   --push  .
```

Before attempting to target an arm I was using skaffold.

Is there any way to continue to target multi-playform whilst also using skaffold to build/deploy?
If not, is there any recommendations for alternatives?

Any advice/help is very appreciated, thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

Found the missing piece. Skaffold has the ability to set a custom command, where I could use `buildx`.

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/custom

```
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: "foo/bar"
    context: .
    custom:
      buildCommand: ./custom-build.sh
```

**custom-build.sh**

```
docker buildx build \
  --platform linux/arm64 \
  --tag $IMAGE \
  --push \
  $BUILD_CONTEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install a driver in order to use both.

https://medium.com/nttlabs/buildx-kubernetes-ad0fe59b0c64

**Edit**
here is an implementation example with a GO 
qiita.com/J_Shell/items/beb266ef65270217a9ed
(please use the translator)

Comment: Thanks, that's a great link. If I understand correctly that would help with a seperate problem where you want to compile buildx using Kubernetes which I haven't tried yet.
I'm not sure if this would help with using BuildX with Skaffold.

Comment: Sorry for that.
I can make an example using Go application, Docker and Skaffold.

Comment: here is an exmple of Go application, Docker and Skaffold 
https://qiita.com/J_Shell/items/beb266ef65270217a9ed (but the page is in Japanese, please use google translator ^^)