# Skaffold: AMD64 dev machine (Mac), remote cluster ARM64 is picking AMD64 images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, arm64, pi, skaffold

Following [Building multi-architecture docker images with Skaffold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067799/building-multi-architecture-docker-images-with-skaffold), I've been able to successfully continue building my multi-architecture (AMD64 and ARM64) images.

However, it looks like the kubernetes cluster ends up pulling the AMD64 image, as I'm seeing:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

in the logs.

I've looked at https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/ but that didn't appear to shed any light on how I can ensure it uses the correct architecture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At its essence, Skaffold is a builder that then runs sed across the k8s manifests to replace image references to the image digests that were built.  From what you're describing, the digest is referring to an image _manifest_ (for a specific os/arch) rather than a _manifest list_ (which points to other image manifests for different os/arch).  You can use `docker manifest inspect <image@digest>` to get the image manifest (you may need to enable experimental support in your `~/.docker/daemon.json`).

Comment: Yes, @BriandeAlwis, you're correct. the skaffold guys have now fixed this issue on their master branch. But have yet to make a release for it.

Answer (score 1):

Skaffold `v2.0.0` and beyond now has explicit support for cross-platform and multi-platform builds.  See the relevant docs here:
https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/handling-platforms/